# Getting the time remaining in the time interval of a Timer in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a sprite "shooting" more sprites every x amount of seconds using a Timer:

```
self.shootingEngine = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: (Double(60)/Double(self.ratePerMinute)), target: self, selector: #selector(ShootingEnemy.shoot), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

So the time interval is defined by:

```
(Double(60)/Double(self.ratePerMinute)) // Let's say it is 2 seconds.
```

The time interval, which in this example would be 2 seconds. It is triggering the shoot() method every 2 seconds. Now, I want to figure out how to get the time remaining until the Timer runs the shoot() method again. For instance, I want to know there are 0.74 seconds remaining until the next shoot()

I was thinking of using this:

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
```

And saving the time into a variable and then just finding the difference with the current time. However, I first wanted to check if there is a simpler way to avoid having to store another instance variable.

Comment: Just use a date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do

```
let timeRemaining = shootingEngine.fireDate.timeIntervalSince(Date())
```

Let me know if you have any other questions. Good luck!