# Swift 4 Get current timeInterval of Scheduled Timer

Tags: swift, timer

I'm using scheduled timer for my application like:

```
contentTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(HandleSendContentTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

It's working well but I also wanted to get current timeInterval when viewDisappearing

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //do something here with time interval

    contentTimer.invalidate()
}
```

Is there any way to get current timeInterval value before invalidate it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609233/getting-the-time-remaining-in-the-time-interval-of-a-timer-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "contentTimer.fireDate.timeIntervalSince(Date())" to get the current timeinterval.

Comment: It Worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Emre Sarıçiçek , Please mark this answer as accepted and up vote it if it helped.